# Something wrong when Executing 2 shell command once with php_exec

Tags: php, bash, shell, command-line, command

I would like to execute 2 shell command once with " php_exec " but it does not work with me.

What I would like to do is that, I enter to the first interface by executing a php_exec, then I execute another shell command with php_exec. It seems to me it does not succeed, I think that just the first php_exec executes the second one not.

As an example we download a zip file with php_exec using "wget" the unzipping the file with php_exec.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't waiting for the shell commands to complete before moving on. You should combine your two shell commands into one.

```
exec('wget http://www/file.zip && unzip file.zip');
```

Comment: There is a mistake I think, I got this : " Fatal error: Call to undefined function php_exec() in... "

Comment: it's simply `exec` rather than `php_exec`

Comment: @Petesh you're right, Unfortunately still it is not working for me ! Actually because the first exec will enter to another console (another bash), then the second one will execute a normal shell command.

Comment: The && in the command means `AND`. What this does is the first command (left side of &&) executes first, and if it returns successfully, the second command executes (right side of &&). Can you test your command in a shell first to make sure it's working, before copying the command into your PHP code?